Is there $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$ such that $\sup_{t \in [0, \varepsilon]} [\ell_t]_\beta < \infty$?
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\bD}{\mathbb{D}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\cA}{\mathcal{A}}
\newcommand{\cB}{\mathcal{B}}
\newcommand{\cD}{\mathcal{D}}
\newcommand{\cE}{\mathcal{E}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\cG}{\mathcal{G}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\sD}{\mathscr{D}}
\newcommand{\sE}{\mathscr{E}}
\newcommand{\sG}{\mathscr{G}}
\newcommand{\sH}{\mathscr{H}}
\newcommand{\sK}{\mathscr{K}}
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathscr{P}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\andd}{\quad \text{and} \quad}
\newcommand{\qtext}{\quad\text}
$
Let $\sP_1 (\bR^d)$ be the space of Borel probability measures on $\bR^d$ with finite first moment. We endow $\sP_1 (\bP^d)$ with the Wasserstein metric $W_1$. We consider
$$
\mu :[0, 1] \to \sP_1 (\bP^d), \, t \mapsto \mu_t.
$$
We assume that each $\mu_t$ admits a probability density function (p.d.f.) denoted by $\ell_t$. We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1), \beta \in (0, 1)$ and $C>0$. We assume that for $t \in [0, 1]$:
\begin{align}
W_1 (\mu_0, \mu_t) &\le C t^\alpha, \\
\|\ell_t\|_\infty &\le C, \\
[\ell_t]_\beta :=\sup_{x \neq y} \frac{|\ell_t (x) - \ell_t (y)|}{|x-y|^\beta} &< \infty.
\end{align}

Is there $\eps \in (0, 1)$ such that $\sup_{t \in [0, \eps]} [\ell_t]_\beta < \infty$?

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

This would be too good to be true! In particular, if this were true then by connectedness of $[0,1]$, it would follow that $\sup_{t\in[0,1]}[\ell_t]_\beta<\infty$. I believe what your question amounts to is saying "If $t\mapsto x_t$ is Hölder continuous in a weak norm, and you have the extra information that $x_t$ is finite in a stronger norm, can you conclude that it is uniformly bounded in that stronger norm?"

@AnthonyQuas Tbh, that general scheme doesn’t sound that unlikely to work… Although I think in this case because OP only assumes a bound on $W_1 (\mu_0, \mu_t)$, $t \to x_t$ is not Hölder continuous in general.

@NateRiver: My answer implements this strategy...

Pick a sequence of functions $g_n$ where (i) $\|g_n\|_\beta=n$ and (ii) $\|g_n-\mathbf 1\|_\infty\le 3^{-n}$. For example
$$
g_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1+n(a_n-x)^\beta&\text{if $0\le x\le a_n$};\\
1&\text{if $a_n\le x\le 1-a_n$;}\\
1-n(x-(1-a_n))^\beta&\text{if $1-a_n\le x\le 1$},
\end{cases}
$$
where $a_n=(n3^n)^{-1/\beta}$.
Notice that condition (ii) implies $W_1(g_n,\mathbf 1)\le 3^{-n}$.
Now define a family of functions $f_t$ by
$$
f_t=
\begin{cases}
\frac {t-3^{-n}}{3^{-n}}g_n + \frac{2\times 3^{-n}-t}{3^{-n}}\mathbf 1
&\text{if $3^{-n}\le t\le 2\times 3^{-n}$;}\\
\frac {3^{-(n-1)}-t}{3^{-n}}g_n + \frac {t-2\times 3^{-n}}{3^{-n}}\mathbf 1
&\text{if $2\times 3^{-n}\le t\le 3^{-(n-1)}$.}
\end{cases}
$$
In words, $f_n$ is equal to $\mathbf 1$ at $3^{-n}$ and $3^{-(n-1)}$
and linearly interpolates to $g_n$ at $2\times 3^{-n}$.
It's easy to check from (ii) that $t\mapsto f_t$ is Lipschitz in the $W_1$ distance. And $\|f_{2\times 3^{-n}}\|=n$. Each $f_t$ has a finite Hölder norm, but there is no uniform upper bound on any non-trivial interval containing $t=0$.
